# JavaScript - Having trouble splicing an item from an array and then re-rendering that array to my page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, splice

Essentially, I'm rendering a couple of notes from a `notes[]` array to my page and adding a button to each note that, when clicked, will remove the note from the array using `splice()`, then re-render the remaining notes. The button is given an id based on the title of the note (given as input by a user), which is also given a similar id.

This is just some Vanilla JS for a personal project and after looking around this morning I've yet to find a solution that doesn't deal with Vue, Angular, or some other framework/package.

#### HTML

This is the relevant HTML:

```
<main>
  <div id="container">

      <form id="utilities">
          <input type="text" name="userTitle" id="user-title" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off">
          <input type="text" name="userBody" id="user-body" placeholder="Body" autocomplete="off">
          <div id="buttons">
              <input type="submit" name="userSubmit" id="user-submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="userFilter" id="user-filter" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
      </form>

      <div id="results"></div>

  </div>
</main>
```

#### JavaScript

The following JS snippets are all in order, simply broken up for readability and comments.

This is the array I'm passing to and pulling from. It takes a title, a body, an id.

```
const notes = [{
        title: 'Grocery List',
        body: 'Buy milk, eggs, and bread',
        id: 'grocery-list'
    },
    {
        title: 'Workout Routine',
        body: 'running, push-ups, rowing',
        id: 'workout-routine'
    }
]
```

This is my function that's getting the title and body text from the user input. It is called in `renderNotes()`.

```
const results = document.querySelector('#results');

const createElement = function(noteTitle, noteBody) {
    const newNote = document.createElement('div');
    const newTitle = document.createElement('h3');
    const newBody = document.createElement('p');
    const newButton = document.createElement('div');

    newTitle.textContent = noteTitle;
    newTitle.classname = 'note-title';

    newBody.textContent = noteBody;
    newBody.className = 'note-body';

    newButton.className = 'note-button';
    newButton.innerHTML = '&#11199;';
    newButton.id = `button-${newTitle.textContent.toLowerCase()}`.replace(' ', '-');

    newNote.appendChild(newTitle);
    newNote.appendChild(newButton);
    newNote.appendChild(newBody);
    newNote.className = "note";
    newNote.id = newTitle.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');

    results.appendChild(newNote);
}
```

`renderNotes()` is simply calling `createElement()` on each note in that array. Then I'm calling it for the first time.

```
const renderNotes = function(list) {
    console.log(list)
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        createElement(item.title, item.body)
    })
}

renderNotes(notes);
```

This snippet seems to be where I'm failing. It *should* be getting each button (created during the `createElement()` calls) and adding an `eventListener('click')` to it. Then it is supposed to look through each of the notes in `notes[]`, find the one which has a similar id to that of the button pressed, and `splice()` that note from the `notes[]` array. Then I simply want to re-render the notes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.note-button').forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        notes.forEach(function(note) {
            if (e.target.id.includes(note.id)) {
                notes.splice(notes.indexOf(note), 1)
            }
            renderNotes(notes)
        })
    })
});
```

#### Actual Results

The notes seem to be spliced from the array consistently, but my problem lies in getting them to re-render. Currently it's just removing the items and then either failing to render or is adding more copies to the page. ***Edit to add:*** I'm not receiving any errors in the console, the code is just executing properly as far as the computer is concerned. So I know it's definitely a "Problem Between Chair and Keyboard" error.

Hopefully this makes sense. I appreciate any responses.

Comment: Where/how is `results` defined? (As in, `results.appendChild`.)

Comment: Also, this breakdown is good, but you'll get more responses probably and it would be easier to troubleshoot if you also post an all-in-one using StackOverflow's HTML/JS/CSS editor. SO tends to be more code- than word-centric.

Comment: Sorry, I must have spaced that when copying over. It's a variable, `
const results = document.querySelector('#results');` between the `notes[]` array and the `createElement()` function. I'll be sure to edit that in.

Comment: @D_N, that would certainly be helpful I think! I'm not familiar with that editor, would you mind pointing me in the right direction please?

Comment: in the WYSIWYG editor, there's an icon that looks like a page with angle brackets on it (`<>`). Click that, and enter HTML and JS in their respective quadrants. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `renderNotes(notes)` at each iteration not only after the array was mutated.

Try something like:

```
const clickedNote = notes.find(note => e.target.id.includes(note.id));
notes.splice(notes.indexOf(clickedNote), 1);
renderNotes(notes);
```

A better solution will be to define `notes` using `let` and then do something like this:

```
notes = notes.filter(note => !e.target.id.includes(note.id));
renderNotes(notes);
```